# Retrive list `<li>` tags having Jquery Selector:ID starts with some format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find elements with an ID that starts with some format?

I have following html list element.

```
  <ul>
    <li id="student_25">ABC</li>
    <li id="student_26">LMN</li>
    <li id="student_27">PQR</li>
    <li id="student_">XYZ</li>
  </ul>
```

I would like to extract list tags having following ID attributes,
`student_25`, `student_26` & `student_27`

```
  <ul>
    <li id="student_25">ABC</li>
    <li id="student_26">LMN</li>
    <li id="student_27">PQR</li>
  </ul>
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of ids then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
//get all the elements with id attribute starting with student_
var ids = $('[id^="student_"]').map(function () {
    //if the id matches the regex then return the id else ignore it
    return /^student_\d+$/.test(this.id) ? this.id : undefined;
}).get();
```

---

But if you are looking for an set of elements then use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var $els = $('[id^="student_"]').filter(function () {
    return /^student_\d+$/.test(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the attribute starts with selector, and then `filter` to find those which have a number. Something like this:

```
var $els = $('[id^="student_"]').filter(function() {
    return this.id.split('_').length > 1;
});
```

Event better yet, use a class to group these elements and then select that.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you colud select by:

```
$("#student_25").css('color','red');
$("#student_26").css('color','red');
$("#student_27").css('color','red');
```

Using pure JS you could select by:

```
document.getElementById("student_25").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("student_26").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("student_27").style.color = "red";
```